# bash: “export: command not found... -bash: export: `/usr/local/git/bin': not a valid identifier when opening terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I followed this setup for git:
https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-the-latest-git-version-on-centos
and seemed like my bash file is broken.
gives me this error:
bash: “export: command not found...
-bash: export: `/usr/local/git/bin': not a valid identifier

Any step by step solution to this? I tried restarting my computer but it still appears.

Comment: You must not have copied the commands correctly. Show what you actually did. Or post the last line of `/etc/bashrc`. There's also a comment at the end of the blog that contains a better command than the one in the blog itself.

Comment: It probably relates to this: `echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin" >> /etc/bashrc` which is just silly (the $ should be escaped) but shouldn't produce the error described unless it was changed in the cut & paste.

Comment: @Barmar I did this: echo "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin" >> /etc/bashrc

Comment: You should use the command in the comment, the code in the blog is wrong.

Comment: Yeah. It did work. But now I have the error. Anyway you can help me with it?

Comment: @Gamaliel Open your `.bashrc` file in a text editor and delete the lines you added to it with these `echo` commands , then write `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin` in that file .

Comment: That's a very strange article. What's wrong with `sudo yum update git` (or `sudo dnf update git` as the case may be)

Comment: @glennjackman: The package repositories probably don't have the very latest version of git.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something like this:

```
export $var
```

and `var` has the value /usr/local/git/bin. `export` wants a variable *name*.

```
$ var=/usr/local/git/bin
$ export $var
bash: export: `/usr/local/git/bin': not a valid identifier
```